# How to focus ion-input with Svelte

Tags: ionic4, svelte

The only solution I could come up with is:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('[name="ion-input-4"]').focus();
  }, 100);
```

With the 4 being because its the fourth page/ion-input. So if you refresh the page it doesn't work because the ion-input name gets reset to name="ion-input-0". But for my application this should rarely happen.

Comment: Are you focusing on page load or in response to some event?

Comment: On page load, or onMount

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options, depending on when you want to focus the component.

1. If you want to focus on component mount or page load, you can [bind](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element) to the input and call ion-input's `setFocus` in Svelte's [onMount lifecycle function](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount). You will also need to await ion-input's `getInputElement` function to make sure there is an input to focus.

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    let input;
    
    onMount(async () => {
        await input.getInputElement();
        input.setFocus();
    })
</script>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input bind:this={input}></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

This can also be written as a [Svelte action](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action), which will run when the element is created and does not require to bind to the input or use `onMount`.

```html
<script>
    async function focusInput(node) {
        await node.getInputElement();
        node.setFocus();
    }
</script>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input use:focusInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to conditionally apply the action based on a prop, you can do the following.

```html
<!-- Input.svelte -->
<script>
    export let autofocus = false;
    async function focusInput(node) {
        if (autofocus) {
            await node.getInputElement();
            node.setFocus();
        }
    }
</script>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input use:focusInput></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<!-- App.svelte -->
<!-- will focus on mount -->
<Input autofocus={true} />

<!-- won't focus on mount -->
<Input autofocus={false} />
```

2. If you want to focus in response to an event (e.g. a button click), you can bind to the input and call `setFocus` on it in the event handler.

```html
<script>
    let input;
    
    function handleClick() {
        input.setFocus();
    }
</script>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Default Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input bind:this={input}></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Focus input
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Another roadblock I have is that I use my own custom component for inputs, that has an ion-input inside the component. I want to be able to conditionally enable autofocus for the custom component. So something like:

<Input focusInput="true"/>

So I need some sort of attribute binding in the ion-input that's inside the custom component.

so far I've tried:

     <ion-input
      use:{focusInput}
    />

but the IDE complains that focusInput isn't declared, even with let focusInput= "false"; in the <script> section.

Comment: You can't conditionally apply an action like that, but you can use the component's props inside the action. I've updated my answer with an example.